# How to log only the message in syslog-ng?

Tags: 14.04, syslog

In `syslog-ng.conf` I have the following:

```
source s_imp { tcp(ip("localhost") port(514)); };

filter f_imp {program("imp");};

destination d_imp {file("/home/rpr/syslog.log");};

log {source(s_imp); filter(f_imp); destination(d_imp);};
```

The output that I get in `syslog.log` is:

```
Apr  8 05:11:20 127.0.0.1 imp[4463]: message
```

I'd like to log only the message and not the time stamp, IP address etc. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the help of templates. `$MSG` has the message contents and we can ensure that only it is logged.

```
template t_imp {
  template("$MSG\n");
  template_escape(no);
};

destination d_imp {
  file("/home/rpr/syslog.log" template(t_imp));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to enable the `template-escape()`, it can also be done with an inline template:

```
destination d_file {
    file ("/var/log/messages" template("${MESSAGE}\n") );
};
```